# myPHPadmin import numbers over thousand with decimals

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I am having trouble importing numbers over 1000 with decimals.

The data is imported via csv.

I am using data type DECIMAL (5,2). However, numbers over thousand like 1005.00 are showing up as 1.00.

**What is the correct data type I should use? What am I missing?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DECIMAL(5,2)` means 5 digits and 2 following the decimal. Since the number you are adding isn't correct it is defaulting to 1.00

Try `DECIMAL (10,2)`